# Pandas: Como posso atualizar valores em dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Possuo duas planilhas onde uma é atualização da outra.

Como posso atualizar estes dados utilizando pandas?

Exemplo, onde 'b' atualiza 'a':

```
a = {'campo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'valor': ["", None, 1]}
b = {'campo': ['a', 'b', 'd'], 'valor': [1, 2, 1]}
```

DataFrames:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)

  campo valor
0     a      
1     b  None
2     c     1


dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)

  campo  valor
0     a      1
1     b      2
2     d      1
```

Resultado esperado:

```
c = {'campo': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'valor': [1, 2, 1, 1]}

  campo  valor
0     a      1
1     b      2
2     c      1
3     d      1
```

Eu tentei em diversas codificões pandas.concat e pandas.merge...
disponíveis em https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/X4WjuLHU